# How to check and uncheck and enable and disable a check Box control in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, checkbox, mfc

What is the source code to do the standard checkbox actions with a Visual C++ MFC checkbox control?

- set a check in the displayed checkbox control
- clear a check in the displayed checkbox control
- enable the displayed checkbox control for user input
- disable the displayed checkbox control for user input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Controlling Checkboxes in MFC

Here's how to check, uncheck, enable, and disable a checkbox in MFC:

```
    CButton* pBtn = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM);
      pBtn->SetCheck(0);// uncheck it
      CButton* pBtn = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM);
      pBtn->SetCheck(1);// check it
      CButton* pBtn = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM);
      pBtn->EnableWindow(0);// disable it
      CButton* pBtn = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM);
      pBtn->EnableWindow(1);// enable it
      bool isRemoveChecked = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_removeProf);
```

Comment: I know I am late but just using it directly should work too, Tested enable /disable of checkboxes. 


Enable - `GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM)->EnableWindow(TRUE);` 


Disable - `GetDlgItem(IDC_SETUP_AM)->EnableWIndow(FALSE);`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you won't need to retrieve a pointer to the button (checkbox) if you use [CWnd::CheckDlgButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98sk2y88(v=vs.120).aspx) to check/un-check the button, for example:

```
BOOL isChecked = ...
CheckDlgButton(IDC_SOME_ID, isChecked);
```

And, enabling/disabling can be simplified to:

```
BOOL isEnabled = ...
GetDlgItem(IDC_SOME_ID)->EnableWindow(isEnabled);
```