# Select/Unselect All CheckBox WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a "select/unselect all" checkbox in a list of check boxes which are dynamically created for a program start up menu. When the "select/unselect all" check box is selected, I would like all the boxes in the list to show up as checked or unchecked. Currently, only the "select/unselect all" checkbox will be selected on click. I do not know how to approach this as the boxes are created dynamically and the values of the checkboxes are only read when the "OK" button is clicked in the startup menu.

```
        // create the structure to store the check boxes so we can populate it on the fly
        CheckBoxOptionStruct* Temp = new CheckBoxOptionStruct;
        Temp->OptionsListIndex = i;
        m_CheckBoxList.push_back(Temp);

        // create the check boxes
        for(int j = 0; j < m_OptionsList[i]->Labels.size(); j++)
        {
            CButton* CheckBox = new CButton();
            CheckBox->Create(m_OptionsList[i]->Labels[j], WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, CRect(Left + 10, *Top, Right - 10, *Top + 15), this, ControlCounter++);
            CheckBox->SetFont(DialogFont);
            Temp->TheControls.push_back(CheckBox);

            // increment the row counter
            *Top += 20;
        }

        // increment the next row position
        *Top += 10;}
```

How it currently works:

[image]

How I want it to work:

[image]

Comment: You need 3 things: `1` [`CButton::GetCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#getcheck). `2` A [`for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for). `3` [`CButton::SetCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#setcheck).

Comment: How would I go about implementing those? Do I need to create a separate function which waits while the dialog box is open? This way it'll have to wait to see if the "select/unselect all" button is clicked, after which it recreates the checkboxes and sets their value to BST_CHECKED.

Comment: @RayH99 simply store your checkbox objects in a dedicated array/vector, and then you can loop through that when needed.

Comment: The checkboxes are created dynamically when the program is started up. This means that the initialization function runs once and the information in the boxes isn't checked until I press the OK button. How can I have it so that the program detects that I've clicked the select/unselect all checkbox if the checkboxes are only created once upon intialization?

Comment: Handle [`ON_BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-button-handlers?view=vs-2019) in the parent window of the checkbox.

Comment: Everything in the box is dynamically created, I'm not sure how I would be able to use the message map for it.

Comment: `ON_COMMAND_RANGE` maybe.

Comment: @RayH99 `CButton::Create()` lets you specify a parent window and a control ID. Make that parent window handle the [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-command) message, looking for the [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bn-clicked) notification, and then use the provided ID/HWND to find the CheckBox that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create user-defined messages and their message handlers.

Link: [How to create user-defined messages and their message handlers?](https://codesteps.com/2014/07/01/mfc-how-to-create-user-defined-messages-and-their-message-handlers/)

Using the SendMessage function to trigger a message and MFC will check the message mapping and executes the associated message handler.

You can check and select the status of the check box in the message handler.

Link: [How to check and uncheck and enable and disable a check Box control in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350537/how-to-check-and-uncheck-and-enable-and-disable-a-check-box-control-in-mfc)

Also note that you set a unique ID for each check box control.

> Detail: When you press the OK button, trigger the message handler
>   through a custom message to check the status of the check box

More information：[Get the notification code from Listview Control checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606686/get-the-notification-code-from-listview-control-checkboxes)